# Error: Received one or more errors Select Menu Builder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When you use the .client command, a menu should appear to edit the bot, but it does not appear.

```
    let OWNBOTS = [allTokens]

    BOTS.forEach(bot => {
        OWNBOTS.push({
            value: bot.user.id,      
            label: `${bot.user.username}`,
            description: `${bot.user.id}`
        })
    })
    let Row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("selectBot")
        .setPlaceholder(" CLİENTS")
        .addOptions(
            [OWNBOTS]
        )
    )
```

I don't know why, if there is anyone who can solve it or offer an idea that can help, I welcome the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the code you've shown the action row you've created isn't being sent anywhere. You can send it as the component of an `Interaction` or `Message` reply, like so:

```js
await <Message>.reply({
    components: [Row]
});
```

or, with a reply to an `Interaction`:

```js
await interaction.reply({
    components: [Row]
});
```

Also, since you're using the builders for the creation of the action row, you should consider using them too for the options within the select menu using `StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder` like so:

```js
new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
    .setValue(bot.user.id)
    .setLabel(`${bot.user.username}`)
    .setDescription(`${bot.user.id}`)
```